# About Python threading Lock Object

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I am reading Python Threading Lock API.
[Link here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects).

I am wondering what does the statement below mean.

"When the state is locked, acquire() blocks until a call to release() in another thread changes it to unlocked, then the acquire() call resets it to locked and returns."

I have read this statement 100 times. Still can't get it.

Why another thread to unlock?
What does the statement after  'then' mean?

Is there any good explanation for this?

Comment: Think of locking like a chair. You have 5 people (threads) wanting to use one computer, if you let them all use it at once it'd cause problems. Instead you tell them they must sit in the chair to use the computer - there is ONLY ONE CHAIR. The first person calls `aquire()` and sits instantly because it is empty (unlocked). The second person to arrive must wait for the first person to `release()` (leave) the chair. At that point, they will now instantly sit down. Whenever somebody is sitting, it is locked. When the chair is empty it is unlocked. If you `aquire()` when it's locked - you wait.

Comment: @Bilkokuya What is difference between block and lock?

Comment: In this context "block" means wait without doing any further instructions. It's just a common term in these sorts of APIs to mean "once you call this, you will sit and wait till it completes - the function will not return until you obtain the lock". Blocking calls do not return till things complete, which separates them from asynchronous calls which will return instantly despite the work not having been finished yet. Blocking in this context is a good thing - your thread will wait to obtain the lock before doing any instructions after the lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overall meaning is that when a lock is acquired from a thread, other threads that call acquire waits untill the lock is released and lock it again:

> When the state is locked,

Thread A acquire() the lock

> acquire() blocks

Thread B try to acquire() the lock, but it is locked, so acquire() block current thread

> until a call to release() in another thread changes it to unlocked

until the lock is released somewhere else (ie, it waits untill thread A release() the lock)

> then the acquire() call resets it to locked and returns.

the acquire() of thread B locks the lock again

Comment: Nice explanation with subject of sentence!! Now I fully understand!

Comment: Can you also explain this statement 'When invoked with the blocking argument set to False, do not block. If a call with blocking set to True would block, return False immediately; otherwise, set the lock to locked and return True.'??

Comment: Why doesn't the statement above like this 'If acquire() is called to already locked lock obejct, return False immediately;...'

Comment: Everything is about the behaviour of acquire(): If you call acquire with block = True, what happens to other threads when they call acquire()? acquires returns nothing: it blocks the other trheads until the lock has been released. if you call acquire with block = False, what happens to other threads when they call acquire()? if they have block = False, they access the lock, if they have block = True, acquire() returns False immediately

Comment: What does your last sentence mean? A little confusing notation, you said call acquire with block = True means waiting in first sentence. But last sentence you said that if they have block = True, acquire() returns False immediately. ????

Comment: What happen when they access lock??

Comment: you have 4 interactions:
acquire(block=False) on acquire(block=False); acquire(block=True) on acquire(block=True); acquire(block=True) on acquire(block=False); 
acquire(block=False) on acquire(block=True). In the first case, both threads run. In the 2nd and 3rd cases, the first thread runs, the second waits, when the first one releases the lock the second start. In the last case, the first thread runs, the second tries to call acquire(), which return False, and ends

Comment: What happen if If a call with blocking set to 'False' would block??

Comment: Can you explain all those cases? It will be great help!!

Comment: @DongukJu To clarify the optional parameter for `block=False` - it let's you use the function as a non-blocking function (one that never waits) which returns `True` or `False` to signal whether it got the lock or not (i.e. returns `False` if another thread is currently sitting in the chair, instead of waiting for it). It's generally used for polling behaviour, where you try to get the lock and if you fail, you do something else and try again later. In general, blocking behaviour (the default `block=True` behaviour) is easier to get your head around and is what you want for 99% of use-cases.

Comment: @DongukJu To expand on that, if you set `block=False`, you are expected to call it within a conditional and handle the `False` result sensibly (i.e. do something else, and not the code you needed the lock for - because you did not get the lock). It moves more responsibility to you, that you have to care/check whether you got the lock or not (`if aquire(block=False): #do something`). In blocking behaviour (`aquire(block=True)`) you do not need to care - the code will always wait until it gets the lock.